# Accessing non-Google Calendar entries on Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, caldav

I'm developing an application that needs to aggregate all locations found in your Calendar.  Can I access calendar entries from any CardDav provider (e.g. owncloud) on Android, or am I restricted to Gmail/Cal only ?

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to download data from the Internet. If that data happens to be accessed using CalDAV, that is fine. However, there is nothing specific for CalDAV built into Android, so you will either need to find a third-party JAR that works on Android and offers CalDAV support, or roll your own CalDAV code.